# Object Oriented Design of a parking lot

Tags: class, oop, object, inheritance

While studying for Interviews, this question came to my mind. 
I am planning to design a parking lot and I am assuming the following things:

1. It has multiple levels. Each Level has 2 rows.
2. The vehicle type could be small, compact and large.
3. Each row at a certain level has multiple parking spots.
4. Each parking spot has red/green light indicator( Red- No space, Green- Free space)
5. Also each parking spot will have size small, compact and large.

6(optional). Also want to add handicapped person situation.

These are some of the assumptions that I could come up with(Not sure if they are enough or I need more).

I was thinking of designing the system in such a way that as soon as the Vehicle enters the Parking entrance.

He should be given information that where is the nearest vacant spot available(For example- Level 3, Row 2, Spot # 10)

I would like to know how to go about designing such a system? I have seen many other designs but none achieves this i guess.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible.  Is that your question?  Whether or not it's possible to calculate something based on stored data?  What are you actually asking?

Comment: I would like to know how we would go about designing such a system.

Comment: That's pretty broad for a Stack Overflow question.  If you make some attempt at designing this and encounter a specific problem we'd be happy to help with that.  But "how do I implement this?" questions are usually too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve through point 6, but the rest are pretty simple to achieve with an OO design, through the usual abstraction, inheritance and polymorphism principles.

You can have an `interface` called `AvailabilityIndicator` which has a boolean method `isAvailable()`, which represents the light indicator (the bulb will show red if `isAvailable()` is `false`, and green if `true`).

You can have an `abstract class` called `ParkingSlot`, which implements `AvailabilityIndicator`. 
This could have the level, row and spot number in it.

You can have 3 classes `LargeParkingSlot`, `CompactParkingSlot` and `SmallParkingSlot` which extend `ParkingSlot`. (Not that your functionality actually needs this, unless the different parking slots have different behaviours or data you want to model, but since you mentioned you wanted an OO approach I mentioned it, otherwise a simple `slotType` parameter in `ParkingSlot` would do.)

Then its a question of when the vehicle arrives, checking what type of slot it needs and looking up which are the available ones that match. You might want to put them in a `Map` data structure which maps each slot type to the list of available ones, so that when one is taken it is removed and put in a separate `unavailable` list, for fast lookup of `available` slots when a vehicle arrives.

Comment: This pretty much answers the question. Thank You. By point 6 I meant that we can also provide separate parking options for handicapped people(as done in many countries).

Comment: Yes but it depends what's special about it. Will it be another different slot from the large/compact/small (i.e. just extend `ParkingSlot` again? Will it be a separate attribute to the large/compact/small (i.e. you could have disabled large, disabled compact, disabled small)? in which case you might need a separate flag in the `ParkingSlot` class and keeping the available disabled ones in a separate `Map` for when a disabled person arrives, in case all others are taken. Do you have special behaviour of this slot, in which case you might need a different OO design pattern?

Comment: Ideally, what I would do is assign specific parking slots(closer to elevator in each level) as designated handicapped parking slots and when a disabled person enters running the same procedure( by just having a flag and the separate map for disabled available parking spots). For general people, I would make sure that my map has all the other slots that are not among any of the designated handicapped parking slots. Does that sound good? Just discussing with you.

Comment: Yep, so the `handicapped` flag could go in the `ParkingSlot` class. Then when creating all the parking slots (depending on the parking lot), those that you want to be more accessible for disabled persons would have this flag set to `true` and inserted in a different `List` or `Map`. Then when a disabled person arrives you look in the special slots `List` or `Map` first before giving him a normal one (if none with `handicapped=true` are available), while normal persons will only get a slot from the normal ones.

Comment: If we maintain two lists `availableSlots`, and `takenSlots`, then we dont really need `isAvailable` method on `Slot` class, do we? Would that be a bad design? Keeping two lists also help fast searching, e.g if `availableSlots` is empty, then there is no available slots on any of the floor. Also, what is the point of `AvailabilityIndicator` interface; who else would ever need such an interface?

Comment: Also, could you please describe the role and usage of `LargeParkingSlot`, `CompactParkingSlot` and `SmallParkingSlot`?

Comment: @Nawaz That is just to illustrate the OOP concept that you can have additional data and behaviour customised for those classes which extend `ParkingSlot` if needed. If it is just varies in size (width and length) then they might not be needed. Maybe the `ParkingSlot` could have a method `accepts(CarType)` which is overridden such that `LargeParkingSlot` accepts Trucks and Vans, while `CompactParkingSlot` accepts city cars... lots of ways to go about it depending on the project requirements.